# How to decimal adjust 4 digit addition in assembly 8085

Tags: assembly, decimal, addition, digit

I am trying to do a decimal adjust after addition creating a 4 digit decimal.
I see that the `daa` command exists but that only adjusts the `al` while I need the entire `ax` adjusted to from hex to decimal.

For Example:

```
mov ax, 9876h
mov bx, 5432h
add ax, bx
```

would result in ECA8 in the `ax` register. The answer after the conversion I want would be something like 5308 in the `ax` register with a carry flag specifying the one before the 5 in the full answer (15308)

`DAA` only affects `al` instead of `ax`, is there some other command to do this or an easy way to do such a thing? (I'm also looking for an idea for subtraction as well since `DAS` also only affects `al`)

Comment: I haven't programmed in 8085 assembly, but your code looks 8086 assembly to me, not 8085 assembly. So are you targeting 8086 instead of 8085?

Answer (score 0):

Since the original example is for the 8086, I'll show an answer with that instruction set. The same principle would apply to the 8085. There isn't an equivalent to the `daa` instruction that operates on a two-byte value. So, you'll have to split up your operation:

```
    mov al, 76h
    add al, 32h
    daa
    mov bl, al
    jnc skip
    mov bh, 1
skip:
    mov al, 98h
    add al, 54h
    daa
    add bh, al
```

And `CF` will be set if there's a 5th digit carry over.